# Python message oriented middleware (i.e. JMS for Python)

Tags: python, jms, message-queue, messaging

What message oriented middle ware with a Python API are out there?
What ones did you use and recommend (or not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember that some people supposedly used spread for message queues http://www.spread.org/, but I don't have any personal experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

For [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), there are

- a Python client based on the OpenWire protocol at http://hiramchirino.com/old-blog/2009/07/openwire-python-client-for-activemq.html
- many Python clients based on the Stomp protocol at http://stomp.codehaus.org/Python

Answer (score 0):

I would also check out [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/).